# Change parameter body and also the value laravel

Tags: laravel, api, parameters, request

i have an endpoint A, but i want to call another endpoint, e.g endpoint B in endpoint A, like this (controller) :

```
Public function loginByPhone(Request $request)
{
        $user = $this->getUser($request->get('phone'));
        if (is_null($user)) {
            throw new \Exception("Invalid user", 404);
        }

        $input = array(
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => $request->get('pin'),
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => env("CLIENT_ID"),
            'client_secret' => env("CLIENT_SECRET")
        );

        return $this->requestToken($input);
}
```

but i want to change the parameter and also the value from endpoint A to endpoint B, because the parameter and the value are different. I was tried to call Request::create and fill the parameter with different parameter and the value in endpoint B like this (controller):

```
private function requestToken(array $input)
{
    $request = Request::create('/api/v1/oauth/access_token', 'POST', $input);
    $response = Route::dispatch($request);
    $content = $response->getContent();

    return $request;
}
```

But the endpoint still fill the parameter with endpoint A like this:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHTnH.jpg)

So what should i do? Somebody please help me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

where do you want to modify the parameters ?

Because in your code is not modify the parameters, and you only pass the parameters **$input** from **loginByPhone()** to **requestToken()** directly.

Is it right **requestToken()** method is returning **$request** not **$response** ?

```
you can check https://pastebin.com/K3KkTua9 ya
```

hopefuly can help :)